# Have the in-game Pathfinder Chronicles been published out of game?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, books, golarion

I have read about the Pathfinder Chronicles that you can find (printed editions) in the Golarion setting. In Seekers of Secrets you can find the content of some editions summarized but I am wondering whether any of these have actually been printed in full as products I can purchase and/or read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really, you cannot buy a physical real-world book for the Chronicles. It is meant to be a vessel for research and in-game motivation for adventure.

"This ancient item is described in the PF Chronicle," giving the GM a two part adventure: 1- Find and read the Chronicle 2- Find and retrieve the item.

You can also see the Chronicles as the stories written later about your players' exploits in the world...

Answer (score 1):

I just saw that many adventure paths have a chapter called Pathfinders Journal where parts of the chronicles can be found. E.g. Curse of the Crimson Throne has 5 pages in each book. This is a good start.

Comment: Sadly, they quit with the journals. But there are dozens of them on several adventure paths.